# Удаление строки из текстового файла в ListBox. Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Есть процедура записи в файл `ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile('notes.txt');`

Его вывода `ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('notes.txt');`

Но как удалить строку непосредственно в notes.txt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Загрузить. Удалить. Сохранить.

Как делается удаление:

```
ListBox1.Items.Delete(42); // удалит 43 строку (нумерация идет с 0)
ListBox1.DeleteSelected; // удалит выбранную(ые) строки в ListBox1
```

Итого:

```
ListBox1.Items.LoadFromFile('notes.txt');
ListBox1.Items.Delete(42);
ListBox1.DeleteSelected;
ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile('notes.txt');
```

Если вам нужно удаление без ListBox1, то используйте TStringList, например.

```
procedure DeleteLine(const aPath: string; aLineToDelete: Integer);
var
  // Локальная переменная вместо with, во избежании путаницы
  SL: TStringList;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile(aPath);
    SL.Delete(aLineToDelete);
    SL.SaveToFile(aPath);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Предлагаю вместо`ListBox1.Items.Delete(42)` -  `ListBox1.Items.DeleteSelected`

Comment: Дополнил, только этот метод у `TListBox`, а не `TListBox.Items`